# Login And logout With Drawer navigation in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer, react-native-drawer

My main issue is after login i want to hide the login from drawer bar and instead of login want to show logout,

```
<Drawer.Navigator>    
  <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
  <Drawer.Screen name="OrderList">{() => (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="OrderList">
      <Tab.Screen name="OrderList" component={CompletedScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Pending" component={PendingScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>)}
  </Drawer.Screen>
  <Drawer.Screen name="EditOrder" component={SingleOrderScreen} />
  <Drawer.Screen name="Logout" component={LogoutScreen} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Comment: `{isLoggedIn ? <Drawer.Screen name="Logout" component={LogoutScreen} /> :<Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} /> }`

Comment: Do you have a variable or state that has the logged in value ?

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
<Drawer.Navigator>
    {isLoggedIn ? (
      <>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Logout" component={LogoutScreen} />
      </>
     ) : (
      <>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      </>
    )}
<Drawer.Screen name="OrderList">{() => (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="OrderList">
      <Tab.Screen name="OrderList" component={CompletedScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Pending" component={PendingScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>)}
  </Drawer.Screen>
  <Drawer.Screen name="EditOrder" component={SingleOrderScreen} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```